# Tinymce capture click event when 'New Document' was clicked

Tags: tinymce

```
setup : function(ed) {
   ed.on("click", function(e) {});
};
```

Tried setting up like this.But this get triggered when I click inside the editor text-area. So How do I capture the **click event** when a user clicks on **"New document"** from **"File"**.Using Tinymce v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE does not issue any specific event when New Document is selected from the Menu.  You can do one of two things:

**1 - Leverage the `ExecCommand` event and look to see what actual command was issued.**
When you select File -> New Document the editor fires an `ExecCommand` event and the `command` property is set to the value `mceNewDocument`.  You can add code to your TinyMCE configuration that looks for any `ExecCommand` event and then checks to see if the `command` property is set to `mceNewDocument`.  For example you can put this in your TinyMCE configuration...

```
setup: function (editor) {
  editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
      if("mceNewDocument" == e.command) {
       console.log('New Document was run...");
      }
  });
}
```

**2 - Build a custom New Document menu option.**
You can create a custom menu option and stop using the default one.  Then you can add your own custom logic to do whatever you need when this option is selected.  You can learn more about custom menu items here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-menu-item/

The default menu option is defined in the `FormatControls.js` file within TinyMCE so you can use that as a template for your own custom button.